# QHash serialization performance

Tags: c++, performance, qt, serialization

I am writing a rather naive implementation of SSTable with Qt. Everything works as promised with read/write/update/delete operations scaling nicely but I found a bottleneck which is the index in both parsing the table into memory and flushing the memory to disk.

I used this as inspiration: https://www.igvita.com/2012/02/06/sstable-and-log-structured-storage-leveldb/

with on-disk compressed `SSTable`, parsed on runtime using `QDataStream` to memory as `MemTable` and accessed using my `TableIndex` which is a `QHash<QString,qint32>` under the hood.

Now when doing some early performance tests I found out that parsing the table of million entries takes about 2 seconds and flushing the table about the same. By examining it further the table itself (being `QByteArray`) is flushed in about 40ms on my computer and with compression enabled under 400ms so storing the index alone takes more than a 1.5 second both ways. The reason is that the `QHash` is actually being accessed iteratively when serializing and is being reconstructed upon deserializing it thus calling `qHash` for every key which is apparently quite expensive.

What I have tried:

- Changing the key to `QByteArray` as opposed to `QString` helps slightly but also comes with a decreased lookup performance (which is lightning fast anyway so not a big deal).
- Serializing the hash as two `QList` objects and reconstructing it manually. While serializing is faster reconstructing takes longer because after deserializing the `QList`s they need to be iterated over and input into the `QHash` by individual key-value pairs.

What I have NOT tried:

- Writing my own hash class because I doubt I would do a better job (i.e. at least decent red-black tree lookup and other optimizations...) or even comparable to QHash. But I could make it so it would (de)serialize a lot easier and faster on the other hand.

I would appreciate any pointers to how to go about this issue, particularly if there is a trick I could use I am not aware of in Qt and/or how to do my own hash without going insane.